# How to check whether an object has a field

Tags: java, arraylist, interface

I have a list of objects that implement `MarkerInterface`:

```
List<MarkerInterface> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Depending on the file I add *Person*, *Biker* or *Dog* objects to the list. These classes implement `MarkerInterface`.

```
list.add(person);
```

or

```
list.add(dog);
```

or

```
list.add(biker);
```

Some of these classes have subclasses: *Dog1* extends *Dog*, *Dog2* extends *Dog*, ...

Some classes have `parentId` field, others doesn't.

I want to check whether an object has `parentId` field or not and print its value if it exists.

How to do it?

I tried:

```
list.get(i).getParentId();
```

but it will not work because `MarkerInterface` can't have `getParentId()` method (not all classes that implement `MarkerInterface` have `parentId` field).

Comment: you need another interface like `MarketWithParent extends MarketInterface` where `getParent` will be defined and then you will be able to use `instanceof`

Comment: Java reflection? http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/fields.html

Comment: @ThisClark. Technically, OP would be better off checking for `getParent_id` as a method rather than a field. There is a good chance that the field would be private for a well-designed class.

Comment: And you should really look into the mental "model" that you are creating. Of course you can use more interfaces or even reflection (my hint: don't go there!)... But: what is the point of keeping so many *different* objects in the same list?!

Comment: @GhostCat. I'm not sure if you understood me. If I have a file with dogs, all elements in the list are dogs, if the file is with people, I add only people to the list. I don't mix objects.

Comment: The question is then: what do you actually gain from keeping a list of MarkerInterface thingies? Just saying: you create abstractions such as this interface so that they help you making things easier... Not just because you can create them.

Comment: I want my list to be able to have person biker or dog because I do many operations with the list and I don't want to write all code 3 times for all type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want to print if the parent_id field is not present?

You can approach this by querying the object to see if it has the field - say, by using Java Reflection to examine the object's fields.  Or, as Lashane suggests in comments, you could add another interface and use `instanceof`.  But I would encourage you to think about other approaches, because explicitly checking a class's fields or interrogating its runtime type(s) is often a sign of a design problem that may come back to bite you later.

An alternative would be to add a method to the interface that returns the string to be printed.  You could have a default implementation that returns "" (or whatever you would print instead of the parent_id, which is why I led with that question), and then in base classes that introduce a parent_id you could override with an implementation that returns the parent_id.

(By the way, it should probably be spelled parentId by convention, but that's maybe not important to the question...)

You might then want to organize the class hierarchy so that everything that has parent_id gets it (and the overridden implementation that returns it) through a common parent class; that may or may not be practical for your needs.  If it's not there are more advanced patterns you could use to minimize code duplication, but that may be drilling a little too deep for the scope of the question.

Comment: And then: a string is a pretty bad choice for something so important as an id. It might be better thinking of a specific id type aka class, too.

Comment: That's true; I didn't see anything that identified the id's type, so just assumed it would be converted to a display string for printing purposes...

Comment: I will use id in some operations which I skipped for now.

Answer (score 1):

As you advised I created ParentIdInterface that extends MarkerInterface and has getParentId() method.

```
if(list.get(i) instanceof ParentIdInterface) {
    ParentIdInterface pi = (ParentIdInterface) list.get(i);
    ...
}
```

Now it works exactly how I wanted to. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Java Reflection, and you have something like this in the classes:

```
public int parentId = 3;
```

You can get the value like this:

```
    try {
        Field f = list.get(i).getClass().getField("parentId");
        int value = f.getInt(this);
        System.out.println("parentId="+value);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException| IllegalAccessException e) {
        System.out.println("no Field named parentId");
    }
```

But i would recommend using Interfaces as the others already said.